# Shutting down SparkContext java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I am running a spark job in our cluster , the job runs for few minutes and then fails saying container exception .I tried increasing th executor and driver memory but no use. I get the same exception again and again . Could any one help with this.

`ERROR scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop: DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop failed; shutting down SparkContext
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "spark.locality.wait"`

```
   17/04/17 15:07:56 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Registered signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
17/04/17 15:07:57 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: ApplicationAttemptId: appattempt_1492433648235_0024_000001
17/04/17 15:07:57 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: xwcedt,ubiadmin
17/04/17 15:07:57 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: xwcedt,ubiadmin
17/04/17 15:07:57 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(xwcedt, ubiadmin); users with modify permissions: Set(xwcedt, ubiadmin)
17/04/17 15:07:57 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Starting the user application in a separate Thread
17/04/17 15:07:57 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Waiting for spark context initialization
17/04/17 15:07:57 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Waiting for spark context initialization ... 
17/04/17 15:07:57 INFO spark.SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.3.0
17/04/17 15:07:57 INFO spark.SparkContext: Spark configuration:
spark.akka.failure-detector.threshold=300.0
spark.akka.frameSize=10
spark.akka.heartbeat.interval=1000
spark.akka.heartbeat.pauses=600
spark.akka.threads=4
spark.akka.timeout=100
spark.app.name=LoadIngestFeedback
spark.broadcast.blockSize=4096
spark.broadcast.compress=true
spark.broadcast.factory=org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcastFactory
spark.closure.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializer
spark.cores.max=1
spark.default.parallelism=1
spark.driver.extraClassPath=guava11-18overrides-0.0.1.jar
spark.eventLog.dir=hdfs:///tmp/logs/spark/logs
spark.eventLog.enabled=true
spark.executor.extraClassPath=guava11-18overrides-0.0.1.jar
spark.executor.heartbeatInterval=10000
spark.executor.instances=2
spark.executor.logs.rolling.maxRetainedFiles=5
spark.executor.logs.rolling.time.interval=daily
spark.executor.memory=2g
spark.executor.userClassPathFirst=true
spark.files.fetchTimeout=false
spark.files.overwrite=false
spark.hadoop.validateOutputSpecs=true
spark.history.fs.logDirectory=hdfs:///tmp/logs/hadoop/logs
spark.io.compression.codec=org.apache.spark.io.LZ4CompressionCodec
spark.io.compression.lz4.block.size=32768
spark.io.compression.snappy.block.size=32768
spark.kryo.referenceTracking=true
spark.kryo.registrationRequired=false
spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max.mb=64
spark.kryoserializer.buffer.mb=0.064
spark.localExecution.enabled=false
spark.locality.wait=3000
spark.locality.wait.node=spark.locality.wait
spark.locality.wait.process=spark.locality.wait
spark.locality.wait.rack=spark.locality.wait
spark.logConf=true
spark.master=yarn-cluster
spark.org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter.param.PROXY_HOSTS=ffhddb10qxdu.qa.oclc.org
spark.org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter.param.PROXY_URI_BASES=http://ffhddb10qxdu.qa.oclc.org:8001/proxy/application_1492433648235_0024
spark.port.maxRetries=16
spark.rdd.compress=false
spark.reducer.maxMbInFlight=48
spark.scheduler.maxRegisteredResourcesWaitingTime=30000
spark.scheduler.minRegisteredResourcesRatio=0
spark.scheduler.mode=FIFO
spark.scheduler.revive.interval=1000
spark.serializer.objectStreamReset=100
spark.shuffle.compress=true
spark.shuffle.consolidateFiles=true
spark.shuffle.file.buffer.kb=32
spark.shuffle.manager=HASH
spark.shuffle.memoryFraction=0.2
spark.shuffle.sort.bypassMergeThreshold=200
spark.shuffle.spill=true
spark.shuffle.spill.compress=true
spark.speculation=false
spark.speculation.interval=100
spark.speculation.multiplier=1.5
spark.speculation.quantile=0.75
spark.storage.memoryFraction=0.6
spark.storage.memoryMapThreshold=8192
spark.storage.unrollFraction=0.2
spark.streaming.blockInterval=200
spark.streaming.unpersist=true
spark.task.cpus=1
spark.task.maxFailures=4
spark.ui.filters=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
spark.ui.port=0
spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir=/prod/higgins/2015-10-07_1/yarn_userlogs/application_1492433648235_0024/container_1492433648235_0024_01_000001
spark.yarn.app.id=application_1492433648235_0024
spark.yarn.historyServer.address=ffhddb02qxdu.qa.oclc.org:8070
spark.yarn.secondary.jars=commons-charconverters-1.1.jar,commons-charset-1.0.3.jar,commons-csv-1.4.jar,elasticsearch-2.2.0.jar,groovy-all-1.8.6.jar,guava11-18overrides-0.0.1.jar,hppc-0.7.1.jar,ingest-batchload-schema-1.0.39.jar,ingest-message-1.0.20.jar,jaxb2-basics-runtime-0.9.4.jar,joda-time-2.9.4.jar,json-simple-1.1.jar,jsr166e-1.1.0.jar,lucene-core-5.4.1.jar,marc4j-2.17.jar,normalizer-2.6.jar,t-digest-3.0.jar

17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO spark.SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from textFile at FeedbackProcessor.java:105
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(283817) called with curMem=306693, maxMem=1030823608
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 277.2 KB, free 982.5 MB)
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(22924) called with curMem=590510, maxMem=1030823608
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 22.4 KB, free 982.5 MB)
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on ffhddb10qxdu.qa.oclc.org:48927 (size: 22.4 KB, free: 983.0 MB)
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Updated info of block broadcast_1_piece0
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO spark.SparkContext: Created broadcast 1 from textFile at FeedbackProcessor.java:110
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO lzo.GPLNativeCodeLoader: Loaded native gpl library
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO lzo.LzoCodec: Successfully loaded & initialized native-lzo library [hadoop-lzo rev 2182b3bcef598d4fa76d3966fca47e80ed7bceb7]
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO spark.SparkContext: Starting job: saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset at FeedbackProcessor.java:235
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Registering RDD 5 (mapToPair at FeedbackProcessor.java:163)
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Registering RDD 2 (mapToPair at FeedbackProcessor.java:139)
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset at FeedbackProcessor.java:235) with 1 output partitions (allowLocal=false)
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Final stage: Stage 2(saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset at FeedbackProcessor.java:235)
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List(Stage 0, Stage 1)
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List(Stage 0, Stage 1)
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting Stage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[5] at mapToPair at FeedbackProcessor.java:163), which has no missing parents
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(3440) called with curMem=613434, maxMem=1030823608
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_2 stored as values in memory (estimated size 3.4 KB, free 982.5 MB)
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(2193) called with curMem=616874, maxMem=1030823608
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_2_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 2.1 KB, free 982.5 MB)
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2_piece0 in memory on ffhddb10qxdu.qa.oclc.org:48927 (size: 2.1 KB, free: 983.0 MB)
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Updated info of block broadcast_2_piece0
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO spark.SparkContext: Created broadcast 2 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:839
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Submitting 2 missing tasks from Stage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[5] at mapToPair at FeedbackProcessor.java:163)
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO cluster.YarnClusterScheduler: Adding task set 0.0 with 2 tasks
17/04/17 15:07:59 ERROR scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop: DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop failed; shutting down SparkContext
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "spark.locality.wait"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:441)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:483)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toLong(StringLike.scala:230)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toLong(StringOps.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager.org$apache$spark$scheduler$TaskSetManager$$getLocalityWait(TaskSetManager.scala:853)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager.computeValidLocalityLevels(TaskSetManager.scala:872)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager.<init>(TaskSetManager.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.createTaskSetManager(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.submitTasks(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$submitMissingTasks(DAGScheduler.scala:872)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$submitStage(DAGScheduler.scala:778)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$submitStage$4.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:781)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$submitStage$4.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:780)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$submitStage(DAGScheduler.scala:780)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleJobSubmitted(DAGScheduler.scala:762)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1362)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1354)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO cluster.YarnClusterScheduler: Cancelling stage 0
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Job 0 failed: saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset at FeedbackProcessor.java:235, took 0.075610 s
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/metrics/json,null}
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/stage/kill,null}
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/static,null}
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors/threadDump/json,null}
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors/threadDump,null}
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors/json,null}
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors,null}
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/environment/json,null}
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/environment,null}
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage/rdd/json,null}
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage/rdd,null}
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage/json,null}
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage,null}
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/pool/json,null}
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/pool,null}
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/stage/json,null}
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/stage,null}
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/json,null}
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages,null}
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs/job/json,null}
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs/job,null}
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs/json,null}
17/04/17 15:07:59 INFO handler.ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs,null}
17/04/17 15:08:04 INFO yarn.YarnAllocator: Received 2 containers from YARN, launching executors on 2 of them.
17/04/17 15:08:04 INFO yarn.ExecutorRunnable: Starting Executor Container
17/04/17 15:08:04 INFO impl.ContainerManagementProtocolProxy: yarn.client.max-cached-nodemanagers-proxies : 500
17/04/17 15:08:04 INFO impl.ContainerManagementProtocolProxy: yarn.client.max-cached-nodemanagers-proxies : 500
17/04/17 15:08:04 INFO yarn.ExecutorRunnable: Setting up ContainerLaunchContext
17/04/17 15:08:04 INFO yarn.ExecutorRunnable: Setting up ContainerLaunchContext
17/04/17 15:08:04 INFO yarn.ExecutorRunnable: Preparing Local resources
17/04/17 15:08:04 INFO yarn.ExecutorRunnable: Preparing Local resources
17/04/17 15:08:08 ERROR cluster.YarnClusterScheduler: Lost executor 1 on ffhddb10qxdu.qa.oclc.org: remote Akka client disassociated
17/04/17 15:08:09 INFO yarn.YarnAllocator: Completed container container_1492433648235_0024_01_000002 (state: COMPLETE, exit status: 1)
17/04/17 15:08:09 INFO yarn.YarnAllocator: Container marked as failed: container_1492433648235_0024_01_000002. Exit status: 1. Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1492433648235_0024_01_000002
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:538)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:715)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1

17/04/17 15:08:09 INFO yarn.YarnAllocator: Completed container container_1492433648235_0024_01_000003 (state: COMPLETE, exit status: 1)
17/04/17 15:08:09 INFO yarn.YarnAllocator: Container marked as failed: container_1492433648235_0024_01_000003. Exit status: 1. Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1492433648235_0024_01_000003
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:538)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:715)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1

17/04/17 15:08:14 INFO yarn.YarnAllocator: Will request 2 executor containers, each with 1 cores and 2432 MB memory including 384 MB overhead
17/04/17 15:08:14 INFO yarn.YarnAllocator: Container request (host: Any, capability: <memory:2432, vCores:1>)
17/04/17 15:08:14 INFO yarn.YarnAllocator: Container request (host: Any, capability: <memory:2432, vCores:1>)




<property>
<name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
<value>5120</value>
<source>yarn-site.xml</source>
</property>


<property>
<name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
<value>1024</value>
<source>yarn-site.xml</source>
</property>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't verify this, but the problem seems this part of your configuration:

```
spark.locality.wait=3000
spark.locality.wait.node=spark.locality.wait
spark.locality.wait.process=spark.locality.wait
spark.locality.wait.rack=spark.locality.wait
```

Property files are not code - you can't use one property's *name* (`spark.locality.wait`) as another property's *value* (e.g. `spark.locality.wait.node`) and expect the first property's value to be used instead.

You can fix this by removing the last three lines pasted here - as the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#scheduling) states, these three properties will get `spark.locality.wait`'s value by default, so if you just omit them from your configuration you should get the desired result.